# Emacs server file path

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, emacsclient

I'm using Aquamacs and started the emacs server with <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `server-start`. My `emacsclient` connects just fine. However, when I start another ssh session (on the same pc) it cannot locate my socket-name / server file. It's not in `~/.emacs.d/server/server` where I would expect it.

How can I find out which server-file / socket-name the emacs server is currently using?

This is my working configuration:

#### `.emacs`

```
(setq server-socket-dir "~/.emacs.d/server")
(server-start)
```

#### `em.sh`

```
location="/`whoami`@`hostname`:$(readlink -f $1)"
ssh <YOU@LOCAL-WORKSTATION> emacsclient -n -s '~/.emacs.d/server/server' $location
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variable `server-socket-dir` (atleast on GNU Emacs) is what holds the location of the socket. The socket file in my case is simply called `server`.

Comment: 'M-x describe-variable' revealed that the value was /var/folders/RK/RK-WFnsWHm0V6eKNHRK48E+++TI/-Tmp-//emacs501 . Tnx!

Comment: What the heck is that?!?!? I don't use OSX so I don't know from personal experience but most Emacsians I hang out with recommend http://emacsformacosx.com/ over Aquamacs.

Answer (score 2):

It's in $TMPDIR/emacsXXX/server where XXX is a number that depends on the version of Aquamacs you're running

Answer (score 1):

This should also fix your problem without needing to manually delete the file.

```
M-x server-force-delete
```